How can I set user parameters in code with DataGrip?
I would like to know if it is possible to define user parameters in IntelliJs DataGrip in a code file or outside the Parameters dialog and how to achieve that.
Background:
I have a (Snowflake) SQL script with some parameters that I need to change from time to time. I like the functionality of user parameters and the Paratemers dialog to set my values but if can set a default value beforehand or define the parameters in the same script it would save me from pasting my parameters in the popup window everytime I run the script and it would be also kind of version controlled.
I am also aware of the Snowflake Session Variables which would work too but only for simple variables such as numbers and strings.

It is not possible for now.
If you want to have some defaults, please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-15478/User-Parameters-allow-to-define-the-default-value

Thanks for the link to the issue tracker. At least it's good to know that there is currently no solution for this and that I'm not the only one who wants this functionality

I tried to do something like this, and what I ended up doing in the interim is to bake CURRENT_USER into the query, so something like this:
SELECT * FROM USERS
WHERE USER_NAME = CURRENT_USER()

The idea came from this thread: Getting grants of current user

Thanks for your answer but this looks like a solution to a very specific problem. The parameters I want to set might not be availabe in the information schema.
